# Get Height of Table Contents in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to get the height of all of a table's contents so I can update the container it is in. This will allow the container and other views in the scroll view to scroll together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set UITableView's height to the height of its content with Auto Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268463/set-uitableviews-height-to-the-height-of-its-content-with-auto-layout)

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43520073/1598912) i answered the same question.good luck

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Swift**:

```
var tableViewHeight: CGFloat {
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

    return tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (CGFloat)tableViewHeight {
    [tableView layoutIfNeeded];

    return [tableView contentSize].height;
}
```

Comment: I think setting height based on tableview content height is not good way as its depend on when you are getting table content height...If you call this method right after reloading table then it may be possible that you might get wrong content size

Answer (score 33):

Swift 3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTbleView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTbleView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if(keyPath == "contentSize"){
        if let newvalue = change?[.newKey]
        {
            let newsize  = newvalue as! CGSize
           tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = newsize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This code is working like a charm, but I have a problem I have two tableview in a same view controller, then this code set the same height for both the tableview's. So is there any other way to get the height of tableview separately.

Comment: if (object as! UITableView) == firstTableView {} else if (object as! UITableView) == secondTableView {}

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be best to add the observer in viewWillAppear, if you modally present another view controller or have a tab bar etc, you will remove the observer and not add it on return. The functionality will no longer be there and the app will crash when trying to remove an observer that is not added.

Comment: Its working but i just notify that your observer call Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
Observer call
that much time execute.

Comment: I think creating a custom Notification that fires only when your data is loaded will solve the problem, the method above works but it will call observer many times... it might cause your app to stutter.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Also works for dynamic cell size.

Answer (score 5):

```
var obs: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

```
obs = tableView.observe(\.contentSize, options: .new) { (_, change) in
    guard let height = change.newValue?.height else { return }
    self.constantHeight.constant = height
}
```