# Calculate UITableView expected height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with 2 cells that do AutoLayout (quite simple, `UILabel` and `UISwitch`, and `UILabel` and `UIImageView`). I want to get tableView `heihgt`. `UITableView` reside to `UIView`, so i did following:

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !isLayoutSubviewsDone {
      expectedHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
      isLayoutSubviewsDone = true
      didLayoutSubivews?()
    }
  }
```

unfortunately, `tableView.contentSize.height` is smaller that it should be. for about 20%. How to get exact height amount?

Comment: doe this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38035450/8374890

Comment: if cell is fixed height with one line label, cellHeight * cellTotalRows = height

Comment: @Evgeniye Did you tried with observer on tableView. If not please try for reference my answer. It will give you exact tableView Height for each and every cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get exact height amount?

There is no magic way to size a table to its contents. The table view has no automatic size. It is not magically sized by the heights of its cells. 
 You have to work out the height of every cell yourself, one at a time, and add them up.

Comment: seems tedious, what amount content size returns then?

Comment: That is irrelevant. And yes, it is tedious. But it is a previously solved problem.

Comment: i asked what is tableView.contentSize.height returns then.. there is an actual value that almost correct

Answer (score 1):

If you add observer to TableView, I'm sure you will get exact table view height. Try below code.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        expectedHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    }
```

//MARK:- Add Observer on Reload tableView

```
   tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "tableViewObserver", options: [], context: nil)
   tableView.reloadData()
```